# Uniqueness and continuity of extension from $\mathbb{Q}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on the set
>   $\mathbb{Q}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of points whose
>   coordinates are rational numbers. Prove that if $f$ satisfies the
>   inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|^{2018}\leq2018|x-y|$ for all
>   $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}^n$, then there is a unique continuous function
>   $F\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x)=f(x)$ for all
>   $x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$. Provide a direct proof without referring to any
>   deep results.

I will be glad if someone will proof-read my solution, since I'm not sure how "deep" are the results that should be avoided.

First of all, note that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|^{2018}\leq2018|x-y|$$
implies
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\sqrt[2018]{2018}|x-y|^{\frac{1}{2018}},$$
so $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2018}$, therefore uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{Q^n}$, which is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define
$$F(x)=\lim\limits_{x_k\to x}f(x_k)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathbb{Q}^n$, where $x_k\in\mathbb{Q}^n$. Need to show that such $F$ is unique and continuous.

Uniqueness follows from uniqueness of the limit. Uniformly continuous $f$ is Cauchy-continuous, i.e., maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, thus extends to continuous function on the closure of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, which is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can my explanation of continuity of $F$ be indeed considered "elementary" or the referred result is pretty "deep"? Does this problem admit more elementary solution?

Comment: It is slightly "deep".  You are basically invoking every uniformly continuous function can be uniquely extended to a uniformly continuous function on the completion.  You should be able to just prove the result in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $F$ is well defined you have to show that if $x_k \to x$ and $y_k \to x$ ($x_k,y_k \in \mathbb Q^{n}$) then $\lim f(x_k)=\lim f(y_k)$. For this use the fact that the sequence $(z_k)$ defined by $z_{2k}=x_k$ and $z_{2k-1} =y_k$ also converges to $x$ so $\lim f(z_k)$ exists. This implies that $\lim f(x_k)=\lim f(y_k)$. For continuity of $F$ simply take limits in the inequality that gives Holder continuity of $f$ and you will see that $F$ is in fact Holder continuous.